# windows - how to make some file impossible to remove/rename for all users via commandline

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, batch

how to (using command-line/batch file only) make some file impossible to delete/rename for all users. I tried attrib +R on file itself and on directory where it exist but it doesn't help

Comment: You can't deny users with administrative rights from taking back access to the file. There are limitations to what you are trying to do. Also, without knowing exactly which user accounts have what permissions, it will be difficult to make this batch file.

Answer (score 1):

CACLS will do the trick. When you say all users however, the system user will still have privileges in most cases.

https://superuser.com/questions/222256/change-windows-7-file-permissions-from-command-prompt

Comment: Not exactly. Calc is depreciated so Im using icalc. It's doing its job but it doesnt matter since user can add permissions to him again

Comment: Once the user has no view rights, they will not be able to see the file. That should make it difficult to change permissions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you can try.

You pass the full path and file to the batch file within quotes for security.

```
TAKEOWN /A "%~1"
ICACLS "%~1" /grant:r SYSTEM:(F) Administrators:(F) users:(R)
```

The `/grant:r` will reset the permissions of the file to what is specified.

Again, if any user is a member of the administrator group then can reset the permissions to any file or folder.